# Compare two sequences IEnumerable.Except in C#

Tags: c#, .net, ienumerable, except

I want to compare how these two sequences are different using `IEnumerable.Except`.

Program description: the program is a Coin Toss Game. 1 is heads, 2 is tails.

The program loops 5 times, each time it loops the program checks if the numbers matched. Numbers are 1 or 2 I used Random. If the coin matches it updates it to the listView.

Label: (`lbl_Numb_1`, `lbl_Numb_2`, `lbl_Numb_3`, `lbl_Numb_4`) generate random numbers, either 1 or 2. `lbl_Result_1` copies the number in `lbl_Numb_2` and adds them to the listview1. `lbl_Reslt_2` copies `lbl_Numb_4` and adds it to the listview2.

I've tried it myself, but I can't seem it get it.

```
private void btn_Match_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //.Next means so that random number is not negative
    lbl_Numb_1.Text = rand.Next(1, 3).ToString();
    lbl_Numb_2.Text = rand.Next(1, 3).ToString();
    //Random Numbers for listbox2
    lbl_Numb_3.Text = rand.Next(1, 3).ToString();
    lbl_Numb_4.Text = rand.Next(1, 3).ToString();

    //This is for the first listbox. 
    if (lbl_Numb_1.Text == lbl_Numb_2.Text)
    {
        lbl_Result_1.Text = lbl_Numb_2.Text;
        //i = shows sequence id
        ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem("" + i);
        lvi.SubItems.Add(lbl_Result_1.Text);
        listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
    }

    //This is for the secound listbox
    if (lbl_Numb_3.Text == lbl_Numb_4.Text)
    {
        lbl_Result_2.Text = lbl_Numb_4.Text;
        //i = shows sequence id
        ListViewItem lview = new ListViewItem("" + i);
        lview.SubItems.Add(lbl_Result_2.Text);
        listView2.Items.Add(lview);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm so confused on what this is supposed to be doing

Comment: Can you include the code with Enumerable.Except() ?

Comment: @psoshmo Hi what part are you confused about?

Comment: I'm not sure why you should use `IEnumerable.Except` in described case. Can you give more information?

Comment: @alexm My objective is to use Enumerable.Except to compare both the listview. I didn't use Enumerable.Except because i didn't know how to compare both the list sequences.

Comment: Basically the program is like a coin toss game. Where you flick the coin 5 times. 1 is heads, 2 is tails. I wanted to know to to use `IEnumerable.Except` to compare both sequences @ArtemKulikov

Comment: it would be nice if the comparison was smallest number first to largest number last. @ArtemKulikov

Answer (score 0):

While using `IEnumerable.Except()` you need to be careful. Because the result differs based on from what you compare.

Example:

```
List<int> l1 = new List<int>();
l1.Add(1);
l1.Add(2);
l1.Add(3);

List<int> l2 = new List<int>();
l2.Add(2);
l2.Add(4);

IEnumerable<int> l3 = l2.Except(l1); // l3 will have 4
IEnumerable<int> l4 = l1.Except(l2); //l4 will have 1,3
```

What you can do is use `IEnumerable.Except` in both ways and store it in a single list.

```
IEnumerable<int> e1 = l2.Except(l1);   
IEnumerable<int> e2 = l1.Except(l2);

List<int> l3 = new List<int>();

foreach (var item in e1)
{
    l3.Add(item);
}

foreach (var item in e2)
{
    l3.Add(item);
}
```

`l3` will hold items which are not present in both the lists.

Answer (score -1):

It's not necessary to use `IEnumerable.Except` in your case.
To compare two sequences is better to use [Enumerable.SequenceEqual](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb348567(v=vs.100).aspx).

For example it returns you true in this case:

```
var list = new List<int>{1,1,2};
var list1 = new List<int>{1,1,2};
var k = list.SequenceEqual(list1);
```

but false in this one:

```
var list = new List<int>{1,1,2};
var list1 = new List<int>{1,2,1};
var k = list.SequenceEqual(list1);
```

Comment: My objective is to use IEnumerable.Except in this program @ArtemKulikov

Comment: It's not possible. Because `Except` doesn't support the order of elements. Sequences [1,1,2] will equal [1,2,1], but it's not correct, right?

Comment: I could customize the program anyway i want, i just have to use `IEnumerable.Except` . If i add another `listView` that contains 1 column that will tell the different sequences. For example on button click: listview1: sequence 1,3,5 had matching numbers. listview2: sequence 2 had matching number. So can i use `IEnumerable.Except` to write what didnt match which was sequence 4 in listview3.